# Gooddata Project Backup

Tags: gooddata

Can someone explain to me how to backup a GoodData project so that I i can restore in case something gets deleted by mistake?

The backup does not need to include the data, but should include everything else (Users, Reports, Dashboards, Attributes, Facts, Metrics, Data Sets, Model)

Answer (score 1):

the best way to backup the whole project except data is using cloning functionality. You can clone the most recent state of your project with or without data.
I believe, the best way of cloning in your case is usage of so called "Grey pages".
The whole process can be divided to two steps: "Project Export" and "Project Import" into newly created project.

For creation of new project, you would need "Project Authorization token". 
Also, your user has to have administrator rights regarding the project you would like to export (backup).

Please, follow simple step by step guide to backup your project:

How to export a project:

1. Go to the project maintenance section at the following url:
   "www.secure.gooddata.com/gdc/md/{project-id}/maintenance"
   where: 
   {project-id} is the identifier of the project you are cloning. This identifier can be retrieved from the URL when you log in to the GoodData Portal and select the project.
2. Click Export. The Project Export screen is displayed.
3. To clone the project, select options according your needs.
4. By default, the user creating the export is included as a user in the generated output. Feel free to add any additional users who are authorized to access the project, separating each user by a newline.
5. To generate the export, click Submit.
6. When the export is generated, the following response is displayed:

   {
      "exportArtifact" : {
         "status" : {
            "uri" : "/gdc/md/project_id/etltask/28f68dea64bcc734d93ca132e4e0b8b000000010"
         },
         "token" : "STGGwCnqyk25ksc"
      }
   }
7. In the above, the export is identified by the value of token.

How to import exported project:

1. After the export has been generated, you have approximately 24 hours to import the export into a new project.
2. To create a project through the gray pages, go to the following URL:
   "www.secure.gooddata.com/gdc/projects/"
3. The Project screen is displayed:
4. Accept the default checkbox values, unless instructed to do otherwise. Provide meaningful values for the textboxes.
5. Click Submit.
6. The project is created.In the returned response, retain the project identifier.
7. Return to the Project Maintenance screen, using the project identifier for the new project in place of project-id below:
   www.secure.gooddata.com/gdc/md/{project-id}/maintenance"
8. Click Import. The Project Import screen is displayed.
9. In the Import Token textbox, paste or enter the value for the token that was generated during the export.
10. To import the source project into the currently selected empty project, click submit.
11. When the project has been imported, the OK message is displayed. Please, note that depending on the size of the project, this process may take a while.

Please, feel free to ask if you have additional questions.

Best regards,

**Zdenek Macicek**

Technical Support Engineer

**GoodData** | support@gooddata.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do [project cloning](https://developer.gooddata.com/article/project-cloning) by using cl tools. May be you need to write script to automatically clone to backup your data.

Answer (score 0):

GoodData does backup all projects and they can be restored by asking GoodData support organization but just in emergency situation.
The retention of backups differs but for 99% it is on daily basis.

Comment: That's great but I need to backup my project in dev in xml format on my local, is it possible?